# how to add a MVC View in template URI of typescript component?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am developing an application in MVC core and angularjs2(with typescript).
I added a  new component (View is placed in *Views\Home\Default.cshml* ) but it is not working.

please see my tried code below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IndexService } from './index.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '/Home/Default',
    //styleUrls: ['app/default/index.component.css'],
    providers: [IndexService] 
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Sign Up';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
    showImage: boolean = false;
    listFilter: string;
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private _indexService: IndexService) {

    }
    toggleImage(): void {
        this.showImage = !this.showImage;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //this._companyService.getCompanies()
        //    .subscribe(companies => this.companies = companies,
        //                   error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    onRatingClicked(message: string): void {
        this.pageTitle = 'Sign Up: ' + message;
    }

    onSignUpClicked(indexService: IndexService): void {       
        //this._companyService.saveCompanySignUp(company).subscribe(
        //    (data) => {
        //        this.company = data;
        //        console.log("Item " + this.company.Id + " has been added.");
        //        //this.router.navigate([""]);
        //    },
        //    (error) => console.log(error)
        //);
    }

}
  public IActionResult Default()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

When i try to run the application, I am facing exception in browser's console.

```
Please specify a ShareThis Publisher Key 
For help, contact support@sharethis.com
util.js:211 Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
aB.j @ util.js:211
http://localhost:5000/Home/Default Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load /Home/Default ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load /Home/Default undefined
consoleError @ zone.js:388
zone.js:390 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /Home/Default
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:468)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:453)
    at zone.js:502
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:154)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:401)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:339)
```

Comment: You shouldn't really use views for it, just put a static file inside wwwroot folder, then you don't have to invoke/evaluate the root every time. Also you won't need to create dozen of controllers. Last but not least, to fully utilize angular2 you'd want to bundle your application files in modules multiple components, views, css and services are merged into a single file and loaded once rather than in 100s of smaller requests. When they point to an controller view, you can't utilize bundling (the server doesn't run during the npm/js/typescript build process)

Comment: Tseng seems very beautiful things but i couldn't completely understand.It would be more helpful if you can provide an example/sample code as well. thank you

Comment: 1. you'd need to post the exception that happens during that request and 2. That would be out of scope, but you should just use static files (i.e. put a file in `wwwroot/app/components/index.html` and set `templateUrl: '/app/components/index.html'`

Comment: Tseng , i have already posted the exception above. please see in the post.

Comment: I cant use static files. because i 'll have to write something by using razor syntax as well

Comment: one view is working. i am getting from asp.net mvc view with the same technique the only difference is that this view is the default view not coming/displaying through router links

Comment: exception 
http://localhost:5000/Home/Default Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load /Home/Default ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load /Home/Default undefine

Comment: Not the exception from your typescript/javascript!!! From your ASP.NET Core application. Since you are getting status code 500 it means there is an error on the **SERVER**. You don't need razor for angular2. If you think you need it, you are doing something terribly wrong. Typescript is meant to run on the client side and has a specific workflow (like bundling and creating modules for lazy loading of parts of the application). When you try to fight this, you will run into trouble sooner than later

Comment: ok thank you Tseng for guiding. i try to use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use   moduleId: module.id in component decorator

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/Home/Default',
    //styleUrls: ['app/default/index.component.css'],
    providers: [IndexService] 
})
```

Comment: thank you Shiva Prasad.
i tried it but where would i get the module Id ?

Comment: i tried the same code as you mentioned but still faced same exception